# Tkinter ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: string, tkinter, casting, floating-point

It's the whole day I'm trying to solve this ridiculous problem, but without success; in this forum there is a lot of material, but usually they are enormous amounts of code and I cannot understand what's going on. On the internet they generally suggest casting but it doesn't work. To make things easy I wrote a sample code to illustrate the issues I'm having in a bigger code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk

my_window = tk.Tk()

my_label = tk.Label(master=my_window,text="N")
my_label.pack()

my_entry = tk.Entry(master=my_window)
my_entry.pack()
N = my_entry.get()

print(float(N))

my_window.mainloop()
```

Very nice and simple, but I get the following message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I tried many possibilities, but anything worked. Any little suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

I want to understand how to assign `float(N)` to a global variable, say `a`, so I can use it later on in the code, and I just took the code of @Cool Cloud and modified it a little

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

my_window = tk.Tk()

a=1. 

def cast():
    N = my_entry.get()
    try: # Try to execute this
        print(float(N))
        a=float(N)
    except ValueError: # If ValueError(meaning it is not a float) is triggered then print...
        print('Not a number!')

my_label = tk.Label(master=my_window,text="N")
my_label.pack()

my_entry = tk.Entry(master=my_window)
my_entry.pack()
# N = my_entry.get() N will be empty as my_entry is empty when code is executed

Button(my_window,text='Click me to convert to 
float',command=cast).pack() # A button to trigger event

print(a)

my_window.mainloop()
```

The output of this is in the following image

[image]

As you can see it directly prints `1.0` without waiting for the assignment `a=float(N)`, so my doubt is how can I actually do this assignment, to use it later in my code. Thanks

P.S.: I understand that `print(a)` inside the definition of `cast()` would give correctly `123.0` in this case, but my problem is more general: I'm trying to understand how to entry an N value, making it float and "propagate" it to the rest of the program. My doubt is given by the fact that `print(a)` almost at the very last line of the program, and still doesn't wait for `cast()` to come in.

Comment: Initially the input is empty, you need to enter data and then trigger an event to change the input to float, I suggest you learn but about event driven programming first

Comment: So there is a way to do it? I know a bit on event driven programming because I have buttons in my code. But I don't know how to trigger a casting

Comment: @CoolCloud Can you introduce the way you would follow in an answer?

Comment: so you have a button, assign a function to `command`, in the function you would call `get` and then do the conversion

Comment: @Matiiss What I don't get is, why should it do the conversion inside a function (I don't understand what does it mean assign a function to command, I'm sorry), but not just do print(float(N)). I don't get it, seems absurd to me!

Comment: because you have to wait for an event (button press in this case), but you don't know how long will it take for the event to be triggered so as to not immediately do the action, you put it in a function which can be called later. about `command`, it is an argument that you give to the constructor: `tk.Button(master, ..., command=func_that_gets_float)` (don't call the function, you need to pass only the object)

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you, it is more clear now. What I don't understand is how can I be sure that casting in a function works, while a simple thing as print(float(N)) doesn't

Comment: what do you mean by _being sure_?, how to know that it successfully converted to a float? or how to know whether you need to use a function or you are fine without? well, first of functions have multiple uses but in this case they just contain code that is supposed to not be executed immediately, when that is not necessary you can execute the code immediately (not using a GUI or sth like that, basically linear programming when one thing happens after another), I didn't particularly understand your question , but also testing, just test what you think would work and if it works, then it works

Comment: @Matiiss I just say all this seems absurd to me; I mean Tkinter is a great package, I was able to make a decent GUI even with knowing very little about coding: is paradoxical to me that I'm having so much troubles inputing floats, isn't it? I just wanted to understand a bit more how this stuff "think", what's the logic behind, because it's unclear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUI programming is event driven, which means you will have to code based on events triggered. *Every* python code runs from top to bottom, and in this case all the code from top to bottom, outside functions, is executed. That means as soon as:

```py
my_entry = tk.Entry(master=my_window)
my_entry.pack()
```

...is executed, the next line to be executed is `N = my_entry.get()`, and at the time of execution there is NOTHING inside the entry widget and hence `N` becomes empty string, and then you are trying to convert that empty string to a float, which will obviously give an error.

What you should be doing is, make a button and when you click it(event is triggered) and connect it to a function that will get the input and convert to float. So that when you click the button you have entered something onto the entry and now it is no longer empty.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

my_window = tk.Tk()

def cast():
    N = my_entry.get()
    try: # Try to execute this
        print(float(N))
    except ValueError: # If ValueError(meaning it is not a float) is triggered then print...
        print('Not a number!')

my_label = tk.Label(master=my_window,text="N")
my_label.pack()

my_entry = tk.Entry(master=my_window)
my_entry.pack()
# N = my_entry.get() N will be empty as my_entry is empty when code is executed

Button(my_window,text='Click me to convert to float',command=cast).pack() # A button to trigger event

my_window.mainloop()
```

Another way, and an unpopular way, is to use `DoubleVar()` which will `get()` the text for you, in this case, your entry will accept any value but when you `get()` the value from the `DoubleVar()` it will raise a `TclError` if it is not a float.

```py
def cast():
    # Unlike before, error will be generated at get() and you dont need float()
    # because if there is no error then it is guaranteed to be a float anyway
    try:
        N = var.get()
        print(N)
    except TclError: # If TclError is triggered then print...
        print('Not a number!')
    
var = DoubleVar() # tkinter control variable
my_entry = tk.Entry(master=my_window,textvariable=var)
my_entry.pack()
```

**Note:** You can do `my_entry.get()` and it wont give any error even if the input is not a float, error comes only in the case of `var.get()`.

Comment: Ironically _"Not a number"_ shortened to _"NaN"_ can be converted to a `float`

Comment: Thank you @Cool Cloud your code works fine. I still can't figure out how to make float(N) a global variable, because I need to enter a value and use it very later on in a program.

Comment: What I mean is that, from your clear explanation, I shoul wait to fill the blanck space with something so I don't get the conversion error due the fact that I have an empty string. But, this means the conversion is made inside a function, `cast()` in this case. I tried defining globally `a=1.` and writing `a=float(N)` inside `cast()`. If at the end of the program I do `print(a)`, it immediatily prints `1.0` without waiting for the button to be clicked! This means I don't know how to program, fine. But how can I export this `float(N)` so, finally, I could use it???

Comment: @RobTan Your entry widget is global, so whichever function you are inside of, just say `float(my_entry.get()` and it should convert whatever is inside the entry at the time the function is executed, regardless of whichever function it is.

Comment: @CoolCloud Ok, you are clear, I think I understood. But, last question, why in the case I said it prints `1.` instead of printing the actual N value in input?

Comment: @RobTan I am sorry, the situation is not clear, can you explain it again? Maybe add that code into your question, so I can see?

Comment: @CoolCloud I do it immediately , thank you very much!

Comment: @RobTan It is because you say `print(a)` in the main block, remove it. It might be a little hard to understand right now, but what your doing is wrong, as I said avoid `a`, and use `float(my_entry.get())` whenever you need to convert to float.

Comment: @RobTan Basically python executes till `my_window.mainloop()` in a single stretch. It pauses at `mainloop()` till you close your application, so basically when you press the button and `cast` is executed, it doesnt matter because `print(a)` has already executed, with its initial value `1.`(even then you would need `global a` inside `cast`, and the code execution is halted at `mainloop()`. If you really want to see it that way, then put `global a` inside `cast` and move `print(a)` after `mainloop()`. There is absolutely no need for any of this, just use `float(my_entry.get())` anytime you want.

Comment: @CoolCloud It worked with the `global a` inside `cast` and later equating `a=float(N)`; when I do `print(a)` outside `mainloop()` it works. I understood better how those things think, thank you. I don't understand your last phrase anyway "There is absolutely no need for any of this, just use `float(my_entry.get())` anytime you want."; this method doesn't work outside `mainloop()`.

Comment: @RobTan You never really want to go outside `mainloop()`, once your out of mainloop, your GUI is closed, it means your application is entirely supposed to exit(unless there is some cleanup activity you want to do).

Comment: @CoolCloud The purpouse is just to exit the GUI and automatically start a program that should simulate a wavefunction, outputting with Mayavi2: is working now, thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

From:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-entry-widget/

"get() : Returns the entry’s current text as a string."

I think that you can't just convert string to float.

Comment: Why? It is possible to convert, but you cannot convert `''` to float

Comment: I did some testing and using float("") or float("some string") will cause that error. However, float("3") is valid, it is also possible to put any string value, even "" , to float if it is done directly without the casting to float.

Comment: @JussiTamminen Thanks for your answer. I read the entire guide of tkinter on realpython and many more, but it was unclear how to use integers or floats as entries. At the same time I saw that people come around the problem with casting, I really can't understand why this doesn't work to me!!

Comment: @JussiTamminen Also I don't understand: "it is also possible to put any string value to float if it is done directly without the casting to float", what do you mean?

Comment: I mean would the code work without errors with this print(N)?

Comment: If you have float f=3.5 and string s="string". This should work f=s, but this not f=float(s)

Comment: @JussiTamminen I am sorry, but why will you even try to convert "" to float, or any other string literal that are not digits to float?

Comment: Work with no errors with print(N), but has no actual output.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting confused: I don't understand what can I do here

Comment: @Cool Cloud is it the problem here? Using float(string_variable)

Comment: The problem is getting the input at the beginning of the program itself. I left a comment in the post too