# Print the selected name of a combobox (elements taken from Sql)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

In a combobox, I load the name of the cities from a simple column of a table. I display them correctly in the combobox, but if I select a city in the combobox (for example London) nothing happens. There are no mistakes, but nothing happens.

I would like to print the selected item in the console. What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I tried to insert an argument, such as cursor.execute ('SELECT City FROM Nations', (cityyyy,)) but obviously I get an error because I can't write WHERE cityyy =?

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.config(bg="gray")
root.state("normal")
  
conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor() 

def combo_city(event=None):
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Nations')
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor]    
    return values

city=ttk.Combobox(width = 25)
city.place(x=10, y=10)
city.set("Name")
city['value'] = combo_city()  

cityyyy = city.get()   

if cityyy:
    print(cityyy)
```

Comment: Just like I commented before in your previous question, learn about event driven programming and refer to the duplicate question. Let me guess, this code returns `'Name'`. As long as you take effort and research, I am helpless. And also "_because I can't write WHERE cityyy =?:_" Why can't you write that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583530/tkinter-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why nothing happens is because simply selecting an item in the combobox does not trigger any events that does what you want. You need to `bind` to `<<ComboboxSelected>>` virtual event and create a function for it to do your specific task:

```py
def func(event):
    print(event.widget.get()) # event.widget refers to widget triggering the event, in this case combobox widget

city.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func)
```

As I mentioned, you need to take a look at how GUI works and how python runs the code, so basically the code at your main block gets executed at run time. Apologies if you got the wrong idea before :)

**Edit:**

```py
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.config(bg="gray")
root.state("normal")
  
conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor() 

def combo_city(event=None):
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Nations')
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor]    
    return values

def func(event):
    print(event.widget.get()) # event.widget refers to widget 

city=ttk.Combobox(width = 25)
city.place(x=10, y=10)
city.set("Name")
city['value'] = combo_city()
city.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func) #update

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. Can you show me how to apply your code to my code? So the complete code of my question. I changed the code of my question, inserting bing and the function. Thanks and sorry

Comment: @Bobby You are almost there, just copy this entire code onto your code, it should work.