# NameError while using Global Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am working on a project in Python with Pycharm as my code-editor.
In my code I faced variable not defined error in spite of declaring it as Global. Here's the code snippet:

```
global hpw
global mil


def bt_cars(hpw, mil):
  hpw = StringVar()
  mil = StringVar()
  w1 = Toplevel()
  w1.title("Choose Features")
  w1.geometry("430x200")

  lb3 = Label(w1, text="Choose features for comparison", bg="yellow"
            , font=('Arial Black', 18), width=25)
  lb4 = Label(w1, text=" ", anchor=tk.CENTER)
  fr1 = LabelFrame(w1, width=20, padx=100)
  hp_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Horsepower", variable=hp, anchor='w', onvalue="Horsepower", offvalue=" ")
  hpw_cb.grid()
  hpw_cb.deselect()
  mil_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Mileage", variable=mi, anchor='w', onvalue="Mileage", offvalue=" ")
  mil_cb.grid()
  mil_cb.deselect()

  lb3.grid(row=0, column=1)
  lb4.grid(row=1, column=1)
  fr1.grid(row=2, column=1)
  root.withdraw()


bt1 = Button(root, text="CARS", width=5, font=('Calibri', 15), command=bt_cars)
bt1.grid(row=7)

space2 = Label(root, text="\n\n")
space2.grid(row=6)

var_stor1 = [mil, hpw]   #NameError here, python doesn't recognise mil and hpw

for i in var_stor1:
   if i.get() != " ":
     work_stor.append(i)
print(work_stor)

root.mainloop()
```

The error for this code:

```
C:\Users\bspoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe "E:/Software/Python    /Programs/School/Project SPASC/SPASC II.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Software\Python\Programs\School\Project SPASC\SPASC II.py", line 55, in <module>
var_stor1 = [mil, hpw]
NameError: name 'mil' is not defined. Did you mean: 'min'?
```

What should I do to overcome this error?

**NOTE: This is only part of my code. So please ignore if import tkinter is missing*

Comment: You didn't define the variables at all. `global` doesn't define variables; it just marks names in a *local* scope as being global rather than local. (As such, `global` has no meaningful effect in the global scope.)

Comment: The `Button` callback is supposed to be a function that takes 0 arguments, as none will be given when it is invoked by the button.

Comment: It's not clear what `bt_cars`  is supposed to do, as the body never makes mention of either variable, whether they are function parameters or global variables.

Comment: I have defined the variables inside the function as StringVar and so on..then why does the error still occur?

Comment: @chepner Actually bt_cars is for opening a new window on the click of a button in another window.
Can you explain about the sentence "the body never makes mention of either variable, whether they are function parameters or global variables" ?

Comment: You have a typo (`hp` and `mi` instead of `hpw` and `mil`), but `bt_cars` has to be *called* first, because you don't provide any definition of the variables in the global scope directly. (Python does not have separate declarations and definitions.  A variable does not exist until a value has been assigned to a name.)

Comment: `global x` does not *define* a variable named `x`. It just tells the code generator that any assignment to `x` in the current scope should create/modify a global variable named `x` rather than creating a local variable named `x`.

Comment: Please post more code

Comment: `mil, hpw` is only defined if `bt_cars` is run. As it is not run, _yet_. It is not defined. Maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585827/13382000) to understand what event driven programming is. Then try to implement a more cleaner solution.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria `bt_cars` gets called when I click the button (it is in a window), then mil and hpw should be defined right?

Comment: No but think of the program flow and read the link I posted. When the code initially runs, you are not running any function. If you want more help, try posting more code

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to get rid of the `global` statements *in* the global scope and put them in `bt_cars` instead:

```
# Get rid of these altogether
# global hpw
# global mil


def bt_cars():  # Button callbacks are not called with any arguments
    global hpw, mil

    # Are these the assignments you want?
    hpw = StringVar()
    mil = StringVar()
    ...
```

If you want to use `hpw` and `mil` in the global scope, you need to either define them before `bt_cars` is called, or you need to ensure that `bt_cars` is called before you try to use `hpw` or `mil`.

Comment: Yep, I want those same assignments.
But I if run the code by doing this, the same error comes.

Comment: Again, because you aren't *calling* `bt_cars` before you try to execute `var_stor1 = [mil, hpw]`. Until `bt_cars` is called, the variables *do not exist*. You may want to at least initialize the variables outside the function, but I suspect your code needs to be reworked more extensively.

Comment: I have called the 'bt_cars' function inside a command argument of a button, before the line 'var_stor1 = [mil, hpw]' . This is that line:-
bt1 = Button(root, text="CARS", width=5, font=('Calibri', 15), command=bt_cars)

Comment: That doesn't call the command. It just tells the `Button` instance to call it when it is clicked. As written, you would have to click the button *before* `var_stor1 = ...` is executed. I suspect that isn't what you want, but it's not clear what you do want, since `work_stor` is never defined.

Comment: Okay, so what should I to resolve this? Because I will only use `bt_cars` function once inside the command argument

Comment: I have no idea. Why is it associated with the button in the first place, rather than just being called explicitly? What do you expect to happen if you press the button repeatedly? Your code has issues that cannot be diagnosed or solved just from the limited, incomplete version you have in the question.

Comment: The function is associated with the button, because I want it to perform the operation of opening a new window and also accepting values from checkboxes...

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back to fundamentals of functions and function parameters and the scope of variables in python. Please go through all the comments I have added in your code. Also, There is very little clarity about what you are trying to do here. I hope it will clarify things for you:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# global hpw
# global mil
# Please initialize the variables with an argument for the function or directly use a value as an argument in yout function
# for example, no need of global keyword, following variables already have a global scope:
hpw = 'a'
mil = 'b'
# it isnt necessary for these variables to be named same as function parameter. The function parameters have a scope local to the function.


def bt_cars(hpw, mil):
    # hpw and mil have a scope local to the function. Also I dont understand their use as in your function you havent used hpw and mil anywhere.
    hp = StringVar()  # Do you mean this hp is the hpw you intended
    mi = StringVar()  # Do you mean this mi is the mil you intended
    w1 = Toplevel()
    w1.title("Choose Features")
    w1.geometry("430x200")

    lb3 = Label(w1, text="Choose features for comparison",
                bg="yellow", font=('Arial Black', 18), width=25)
    lb4 = Label(w1, text=" ", anchor=CENTER)
    fr1 = LabelFrame(w1, width=20, padx=100)
    hp_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Horsepower", variable=hp,
                        anchor='w', onvalue="Horsepower", offvalue=" ")
    hp_cb.grid()
    hp_cb.deselect()
    mil_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Mileage", variable=mi,
                         anchor='w', onvalue="Mileage", offvalue=" ")
    mil_cb.grid()
    mil_cb.deselect()

    lb3.grid(row=0, column=1)
    lb4.grid(row=1, column=1)
    fr1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    root.withdraw()


# The function arguments here?? You could use lambda here
bt1 = Button(root, text="CARS", width=5, font=('Calibri', 15), command=bt_cars)
bt1.grid(row=7)

space2 = Label(root, text="\n\n")
space2.grid(row=6)

var_stor1 = [hpw, mil]  # There wont be any error now.
```

Comment: I apologize for the variable mismatch..indeed I need hpw and mil only.
I just need two clarifications:-
1) If I just initialize the variables outside the function with any value, Global won't be needed?
2) Also, what is the lambda function here? (I am a new programmer, so please tolerate my ignorance of it)

Comment: Clicking on the button is going to give an error

Comment: @vivekkumar @DelriusEuphoria Yes, it is showing the following error:-

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bspoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: bt_cars() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'hpw' and 'mil'

`
What could be wrong?

Comment: In Python, global keyword allows you to modify the variable outside of the current scope. It is used to create a global variable and make changes to the variable in a local context. If your function is modifying the variables declared outside the function, you could use the global keyword inside the function code block.

Comment: You could try: textvariable=hp, command=lambda: bt_car(hp, mi) to call your function with the arguments

Comment: @vivekkumar Actually if I give the argument `textvariable=hp`, the editor raises an error showing the argument is not needed.  When I run without `textvariable=hp`, though the same error of hp not defined persists

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the value of a global variable inside a function, you must declare it global inside the function.

You should check the file of ASCII .line 55

Comment: I did like you suggested, but the same error still persists